# paintComponent and repaint methods not working for my JPanel, Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I am working on trying to make a GUI with a rectangular vehicle object in the middle of the page with regards to x-coordinate and two rectangular objects on either side of the vehicle.

I am extending a JPanel, so I call repaint in the run method to call the paintComponent method, but I am not even entering the paintComponent method. Additionally, do I have to do anything differently because I am working with Graphics2D?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Display extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    public static final int frameWidth=1300;
    public static final int frameHeight=800;
    public double score;
    public double updateTimeInterval=25;
    public double prevUpdatedTime=0;

public Display(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    frame.setTitle("You are playing HoverTeam!!!");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    System.out.println("completed constructor.");
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    System.out.println("currently painting.");
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    /*
     * Testing with random GameState
     */
    double[] pos = {28,6,Math.PI/8};
    double[] vel = {5,5,0};
    int[] nearList = {4,8,7,5};
    GameState gs = new GameState(pos,vel,2,2,nearList,3);
    //GameState gs = GameClient.getGameState();
    /*
     * Drawing the vehicle in the center of the screen with regards to the x-coordinate and then referencing the walls to it.
     */
    Path2D.Double vehic = gs.getVehicleShapePath(frameWidth/2, gs.getPosition()[1]);
    g2.draw(vehic);
    int[] nearObstHeights = gs.getNearObstList();
    double vehiclePast = gs.getPosition()[0]%5; //distance that the vehicle is past the second obstacle--reference to where to draw obstacles
    for (int i =0; i<nearObstHeights.length;i++){
        Rectangle2D.Double obstacle = new Rectangle2D.Double(frameWidth/2 -vehiclePast+5*(i-1),nearObstHeights[i],1,nearObstHeights[i]);
        g2.draw(obstacle);
    }
    score = gs.getPosition()[0]/5;
    g.drawString("Score:"+score, frameWidth/2, frameHeight-10);

}
public void run(){
    /*
     * No maximum score, game goes on forever.
     */

    System.out.println("entereed run method.");
    while (true){   
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime-prevUpdatedTime>updateTimeInterval){
            System.out.println("entered if statement");
            prevUpdatedTime = currentTime;
            repaint();
            System.out.println("should have just repainted.");
        }
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    (new Thread(new Display())).start();
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Where do you think you are instantiating an object `Display` that would make use of the `paintComponent` (i.e. that it's being shown in the GUI)?

Comment: Yes, you're adding some plain JPanel to your JFrame and not adding any objects of the Display class to anything that is displayed. Also, as an aside, your paintComponent method appears dangerous in that you appear to have code logic in this method which changes the state of your class, and that shouldn't be.

Comment: I thought by calling (new Thread(new Display())).start() in the main method; I would be calling the run method of the Display object, which in turn calls paintComponent when I call repaint in the run method.

Comment: @user3014093 calling start() certainly executes run(). But you never put any Display object in your GUI. Display is a JPanel it has to go inside a Frame. Before messing with paintComponent just try to make a simple GUI. you are missing some key understanding of Swing.

Comment: Yes currently I have the paintComponent method call a synchronized method to get a gameState and then paint that. However, to test it out I just made an example gameState and want to see if it displays. Why is that dangerous?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very confusing, each object has to take care of its own responsabilities and nothing more. In particular:

- Display is a JPanel... and also a Runnable? Why is that? You can have a runnable doing work with the GUI (carefully) but it shouldn't be the GUI itself.
- Display is a JPanel but its constructor is doing all sorts of things like creating a frame. The constructor of Display only has to take care of *constructing* the JPanel. Create your own class `MyApplication` that does all the work, or an static method `createAndShowGUI()` and call it from your main.
- Why are you creating a thread in the main? Or rather, why the same statment that creates the

Then you have some problems in your code:

- The first thing you almost certianly do in your `paintComponent` is calling `super.paintComponent(g)`.
- You should learn what the Event Dispatching Thread is. Look at how to setup the [initial threads in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). In short you must call `invokeLater` in your main and get rid of that `new Thread()`. And however you organize your code, do not execute that runnable in the EDT, it has an infinite loop and the GUI would freeze.
- You never put any Display object in your frame. The code creating the GUI should be something like this:

.

```
//we create the GUI here, this is called by main inside the runnable of `invokeLater`.
public static creteAndShowGUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    frame.setTitle("You are playing HoverTeam!!!");


    //JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //this is an empty panel, you want the Display subclass that you created.

    //we use the Display panel that will use the `paintComponent` to paint itself
    Display panel = new Display();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    System.out.println("completed constructor.");

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

You don't need that runnable at all, the GUI is repainted when needed by its own. You only have to call repaint() if you are making changes in it with your code.

**Edit:** As per your comments I'll clarify something: What`repaint()` does is schedule the repainting of the object in the screen, that process includes, at some point, calling `paintComponent`. However you are calling `repaint()` on an object that it's not in the screen. Your call `repaint()` or rather `this.repaint()` is repainting the object `new Display()` that you create in the `main` (and is aregument of `new Thread()` however you don't add that object to any frame, it's not in the GUI so there's nothing to repaint on the screen.